# How do I change the default shell for `sh-mode`?

Tags: sh-mode

`sh-mode` usually does a great job of auto-magically detecting which shell a file is intended to be run by. It looks at the shebang, for instance. However, I have a bunch of files that are intended to be sourced, not run as executables, and thus I don't have a shebang.

I have my `$SHELL` environment variable set to `bash`, but when I open the file, `sh-mode` still defaults to `sh`. How do I get it to default to `bash`?

I've tried running `(getenv "SHELL")` in both `*scratch*` and with `eval-expression` in the shell file's buffer, and they both report `"usr/loca/bin/bash"`. Why doesn't `sh-mode` respect this? I've been digging through the source code and it really seems like this should be working.

Answer (score 1):

As @RichieHH mentioned you can set `sh-shell-file` via the custom facility or directly for a global default.

Alternatively, and my preferred method, is to set the shell via file-local variables. For example, the first line of your file could look like:

```
## -*- mode: shell-script; sh-shell: zsh; sh-basic-offset: 3; sh-indentation: 3; coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This sets the local file to `shell-script` mode, using the `zsh` shell, and indentation to 3.  (The variable `sh-shell` is what is set when you call `M-x sh-set-shell`.) `shell-script-mode` will then figure out `sh-shell-file` on its own (presumably based on your path.)

Obviously, you could do something similar with directory local variables.

Comment: Since I often use `vim` to make quick edits, `## vim: ts=3:sts=3:sw=3:et:ft=zsh
` would be a similar modeline.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at `sh-shell-file`? It picks up the shell from that I think reading the docstring.